# check if heuristics is compatible

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

i know that compatible heuristics is the one that under these condition :
h(n) <= c(n,a,n') + h(n').
 Andthe admissible heuristics is under condition: 0 <= h(n) <= the real cost. However, I don't know how to check if this heuristics is compatible : 
An agent lives in an NxN gridworld. The agent's current position is given by the tuple (Xa; Ya) representing the row and
column it is currently in. The goal location the agent wants to reach is represented by the tuple (Xg; Yg). The agent can only
move up, down, left, or right 1 square at a time.

h(a) = (Xa - Xg) + (Ya - Yg)
Can I have some hints to do this? thank you so much.

Comment: Is this for the A* pathfinding algorithm?

Comment: yes, this is for the A* pathfinding

Comment: Honestly, easier to go lookup a simple A* done in C++ and learn from that.  Your high level description of stuff just muddles the job I believe.

Answer (score 2):

For A* pathfinding, the taxicab distance is a good heuristic in your case as far as I know. More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As @FeiXiang correctly pointed out, you should go with the taxi cab distance also known as the Manhattan distance in your case where the only valid moves are up, down, left, or right.

If `(Xa, Ya)` is your current position in the grid `Point a` and `(Xb, Yb)` is your destination `Point b`, then you would compute the Manhattan distance as the following.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Point;
unsigned manhattanDistance(const Point &a, const Point &b)
{
    return abs(a.first - b.first) + abs(a.second - b.second);
}
```

There are plenty of resources on the Internet for help with the [A* search algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/) so start hitting the books and good luck!

Comment: In his problem the only possible moves are up, down, left, and right. So the taxicab distance is a better heuristic than the Euclidean distance. By the way, you don't need to take the absolute value since you immediately square the value afterward.